# How can I run swipe and tap commands when my app isn't in focus?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, background

I am trying to make an app that has the ability to tap on the screen of the phone when the UI is not in focus. I have tried making a service, as well as creating a new thread which that service runs through, yet I still seem to have no luck.

Here is my service declaration in my AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Tap_Service"/>
```

Here is the code from my MainActivity class to show the command I am trying to do:

```
public void begin_thread(View view){
        startService(new Intent(this, Tap_Service.class));
    }
    public void end_thread(View view){

    }

    static class FirstThread extends Thread {
        int seconds;
        FirstThread(int seconds){
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++){
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("input", "tap", "539", "1120");        
                try {
                    Process pc = pb.start();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Clicked");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error on click");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the code for my service class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Tap_Service extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    private static final String TAG = "Feedback: ";


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        MainActivity.FirstThread thread = new MainActivity.FirstThread(3);
        thread.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
}
```

Here is why I am so confused; if my commands are to run logs, then the logs are properly shown in Android Studio, even when I leave my app. This tells me the background service is running properly, and the fact that my UI doesn't freeze tells me my other thread is working properly as well. The only time it does not work is when I try to tap the screen outside the app. Otherwise, the taps work perfectly. When I press the button `begin_thread`, it always says in the log that it clicked successfully. This is true when I have the app open, but when it's not, the log still continues to say "Clicked", when though my screen was not tapped. Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" -- apps cannot inject input events into other apps, for privacy and security reasons, except via the accessibility APIs.

Comment: Ah, that does explain it. Thank you.